# Изменение размера и жирности шрифта в заголовке текста, внутри richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Имеется richtextbox, текст в нем меняется по клику кнопки, у каждого куска текста есть свой заголовок.

Разобрался как выделить заголовок и изменить ему цвет, есть ли возможность сделать его жирным, выровнять по центру, и сделать на кегль больше чем текст под ним?

На загрузке формы:

```
richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
int newFontSize = 16; //размер
richTextBox1.Font = new Font(richTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, (float)newFontSize);
```

По клику:

```
richTextBox1.Text = "Полимерные материалы: технология, виды, производство и применение.\nПолимерные материалы - это химические высокомолекулярные соединения, которые состоят из многочисленных маломолекулярных мономеров (звеньев) одинакового строения. Зачастую для изготовления полимеров используют следующие мономерные компоненты: этилен, винилхлорид, винилденхлорид, винилацетат, пропилен, метилметакрилат, тетрафторэтилен, стирол, мочевину, меламин, формальдегид, фенол. Далее будет подробно рассмотрено, что такое полимерные материалы, каковы их химические и физические свойства, классификация и виды. ";
richTextBox1.Select(0, "Полимерные материалы: технология, виды, производство и применение.".Length);
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.DarkGray;
```

UPD1: Нашел выравнивание по центру, но к заголовку, как кусочку текста, применить не вышло. `richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;`

Comment: Думаю, вам нужно отказаться от работы с RTF через RichTextBox. Вы уже поняли, что это крайне неудобно. И к тому же, это работает очень медленно. Используйте какую-нибудь [библиотеку](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=rtf) для работы с RTF. В частности, [вот](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/How-to-create-RTF-document-2e78819c) или [вот](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98062/RTF-Document-Constructor-Library).

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Шрифт(Font)                Сам шрифт,размер,стиль
            richTextBox1.Font = new Font("Consolas", 18f, FontStyle.Bold);
            //Меняем цвет фона
            richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
            string[] words =
            {
               ...
            };
            Color[] colors =
            {
                ...
            };

            //some code
        }
    }
}
```

UPD: Думаю,что нельзя менять отдельный текст

```
        richTextBox1.Font = new Font("Consolas", 10f, FontStyle.Strikeout);
        richTextBox1.Text += "Hello \n";
        richTextBox1.Font = new Font("Consolas", 26f, FontStyle.Italic);
        richTextBox1.Text += "World";
```

Я попробовал разными способами

Comment: Немного не поняли. Нужно изменить размер заголовка и выровнять его по центру `richtextbox`. Данное решение повлияет на весь текст внутри контейнера, либо я немного недопонимаю, как использовать

Comment: Можно, вот вам пример) `richTextBox1.Select(0, "Полимерные материалы:\n технология, виды, производство и применение.".Length);
                richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;`

Comment: Единственное, что не выходит изменить размер заголовка.

Comment: @LokenGarvel' я про шрифт,как вы сделали разный шрифт у строк? PS мне оч интересно

Comment: c помощью выделенного текста, берем что-либо в блок, и работаем дальше только с ним. Например :richTextBox1.Select(0, "Каландровый метод\n производства полимерных пленок.".Length);`, и теперь все дальнейшие действия будут происходить с заselectанным текстом - richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black; и так далее

Comment: Прошу прощения, код не хочет выделяться.